# Orderby & sort not returning entries

Tags: add-on, channel-entries, playa

I'm using the code below on EE2.5.3 and playa 4.3.3 and am not getting expected results. With the orderby and sort parameters in place, I only get 1 entry returned.

If I remove the orderby and sort parameters I get 4 entries returned, albeit not in the order I want.

Can anyone explain this disparity?

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="subcontractors" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
        {if {exp:playa:total_parents} >= 1}
            <li>{title} &rarr; {exp:playa:total_parents} Warranty items</li>
        {/if}       
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: If you leave the sort and orderby params, and comment out the Playa conditional, do you still only see one entry? You may be seeing more, but your Playa conditional prevents them from appearing.

Comment: Removing the playa conditional results in all entries being returned in the expected order. About 100 entries. Of course I only want to return entries with 1 or more parents associated.

Comment: Okay, it's the EE inbuilt 100 entry limit that is the problem. Using the limit parameter to increase this has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Playa Children](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates#playa%3achildren) tag to show children, rather than the channel entries tag and then a conditional.

```
{exp:playa:children field="field_where_relationship_was_made"}
  <li>{title} &rarr; {exp:playa:total_parents} Warranty items</li>
{/exp:playa:children}
```